# PHP Parse a Node detail in XML and combine into a clickable URL

Tags: xml-parsing

I have a XML node named "ID" and contains alphanumeric e.g 123xyz.  I have another standard website url e.g staffexam.com which is not in the XML node.

Now I want to parse the "ID" with the website url "staffexam.com"

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("exam.xml");
foreach ( $xml->ID as $examID )
{
echo " URL: ", " http://", $examID, ".staffexam.com", "\n";
}
?>
```

The end result shows http://123xyz.staffexam.com but it is in plain text.  How do I convert this into a clickable url?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ( $xml->ID as $examID )
{
$url = "http://" . $examID . ".staffexam.com";
echo " URL: <a href=\"$url\">$url</a>\n";
}
```